# "Проиграть войну с болезнью" и "проиграть войну против болезни"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *она проиграла войну с болезнью* или *она проиграла войну против болезни*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПРОИГРА́ТЬ,  1. **что или что кому.** Окончить что-нибудь с неудачей, потерпеть неудачу в чем-нибудь (игре, споре, состязании, столкновении с кем-нибудь).

"Я проиграл войну **с болезнью** и с судьбою, и не дрожит уже безумства тетива".

Войну **против болезни** тоже можно проиграть или выиграть.

Но проиграть войну **(чему?)** болезни нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, Vera!